# what is the difference between statiscal averagre and average?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, average, means

I'm reading a book on synthetic aperture radar and it is said that:

> The term $\sigma^{\circ}$ is the averaged radar cross section per unit
>   area, also called the scattering coefficient or `sigma-naught` and
>   represents the ratio of the **statistically averaged** scattered power
>   density to the **average** incident power density over the surface of
>   the sphere of radius r with

$$\sigma^{\circ}=\frac{\langle\sigma\rangle}{A_0}=\frac{4\pi r^2}{A_0}\frac{\langle|\vec E_S|^2\rangle}{|\vec E_I|^2}$$
I mean what statistical or mathematical concept does the $\langle\;\rangle$ show here?

---

From statistics which I have studied in the first year of university I'm familiar with these concepts:

arithmetic mean for the sample: $$\overline x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$
arithmetic mean for the society:$$\mu=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{N}$$
Expected value for a discrete random variable:$$E(X)=\sum_{\forall x_i}x_iP_X(x_i)$$
Expected value for a continuous random variable: $$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_X(x)dx$$
$f_X(x)$ and $P_X(x_i)$ are probability density functions.

But I don't know which of them is called average and which one is called statistical average?
what's the purpose of average and statistical average?
what's the mathematical formula for each of them?

Comment: Sounds like skolnik radar text book! :), however, since you dont have access to probability (PDF) density function of the RCS, you must use the statistical averaging.

Comment: statistical averaging can be considered equal to $E[.]$, when the RCS be Ergodic. in this case, you can assert, the time average or <> would be equal to $E[.]$. where E stands for expectation.

Comment: @Cardinal Could you please give me the formula for each?

Comment: have a look at this:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFgQFjAHahUKEwjT7-qs4IjHAhXItBQKHWjOAl4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fce.sharif.ir%2Fcourses%2F89-90%2F1%2Fce695-1%2Fresources%2Froot%2FClassNotes%2FErgodicity.pdf&ei=_i-9VdP4NMjpUuici_AF&usg=AFQjCNEBa2N3svutTh6ohaudA5vzIWgoDg&sig2=bs4pvzK4LK-4ho2U9f_gfg&bvm=bv.99261572,d.bGg

Comment: @Cardinal seems that you are iranian. Can I have your email just for a few question about the lecture notes of sharif on stochastic processes that you suggested in the previous comment. I will email my questions in a day or two and try not to disturb you

Comment: Yes I am. But I am not one of them, I mean the sharifaians !! Although I am very busy with my thesis currently, feel free to contact me here: o.caspian@yahoo.com
I regularly check this E-mail for notifications of this site and the others similar ones.

Comment: Hopefully, I recommend you to ask this question in Research gate. There are specialists having skills about your question.